# Creating a random number using JavaScript and returning in HTML without using form

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Is it possible to generate a random number from JavaScript to HTML using button `onclick` but return it through a `<div>` ? I have looked at other similar questions but they all seem to use either `<input>` or `<form>`. I am not getting any errors in my browser, when I try this code but the output is coming from the `<div>` saying 'undefined' as opposed to a number so I'm obviously not defining `number` but I'm just a bit confused by JavaScripts syntax.

## /// HTML ///

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="randRandomScript.js">
</script>    
</head>

<body>

 <button name="randNumberButton" onclick="randNumberScript()" >Click for Number</button>

<div id="number"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

## /// JavaScript ///

```
var randomNumberObject = math.floor(math.random()*10);

 function randNumberScript () {

document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = randomNumberObject;

}
```

Comment: A side note: if you want to set the text inside an HTML element, it is better to set [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) than [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). `textContent` doesn’t try to interpret the string as HTML, so it runs faster, and it will let you include characters like `<>`.

Comment: Interesting, is there any occasion when innerHTML would be better to use?

Comment: `innerHTML` is a convenient way to insert multiple HTML elements inside an element, such as `the secret numbers are <b>5</b> and <b>7</b>`. It can be a quick way to test some code to set element contents, but usually you should use other methods once you understand the structure you want. The problem with `innerHTML` is that if the string you are assigning contains user input, for example if the user typed in `5` and `7`, then the user could type HTML like `<h1>5</h1>` and mess up the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `randomNumberObject` variable as `local-variable` or else it will not be updated every time button clicked.

**Note:** Correct the typo @ `math`.. It is **`Math`**

```js
function randNumberScript() { //Why are you accepting a argument ?
  var randomNumberObject = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //typo at Math
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = randomNumberObject;
}
```

```html
<button name="randNumberButton" onclick="randNumberScript()">Click for Number</button>

<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked perfectly. Although I'm a bit disappointed that I was so close to getting there myself.. Can I ask why it needs to be used locally?

Comment: @eainnem Global variable will not affect inside the function..To get the new value, handle it inside the function..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead your code because your code is using invalid syntax and also no need to write the javascript function in seperate file ,just write the function in a script tag just above the closing body tag().

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```